# flutter speech-to-text plugin automatically stops capturing audio

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, dart-pub

I've implemented a speech-to-text service in flutter using the speech-to-text widget.It basically listens to what ever the user say and when he says period, it should send the the captured sentences to the flask backend.Below is the code,

```
class _AudioInputViewState extends State<AudioInputView> {
  late UnityWidgetController _unityWidgetController;
  String sentence1 ="";
  String sentence2 ="";
  List<String> sentences=[];
  List<String> sentenceTokens=[];
  int starterIndex=0;
  final Map<String, HighlightedWord> _highlights = {
    'period': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('period'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  };
  late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Press the button and start speaking';
  double _confidence = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

      ),
      body:
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Colors.blue.shade700, Colors.green.shade700],
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Translator App",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 150.0),
                  child: TextHighlight(
                    text: _text,
                    words: _highlights,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              AvatarGlow(
                animate: _isListening,
                glowColor: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .primaryColor,
                endRadius: 75.0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                repeatPauseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                repeat: true,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _listen,
                  child: Icon(
                    _isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none,
                    size: 32,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _listen() async {
    final TranslatorProvider translatorProvider =
    Provider.of<TranslatorProvider>(context, listen: false);
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) {
            setState(() {
              _text = val.recognizedWords;
              sentenceTokens.clear();
              List<String> words = _text.split(" ");
              for (int i = starterIndex; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (words[i] == "period") {
                  String sentence = sentenceTokens.join(' ');
                  sentences.add(sentence);
                  sentenceTokens.clear();
                  print(sentences);
                  print("---------------------------");
                  print(sentences.last);
                  starterIndex = i + 1;
                  translatorProvider.sendText(sentences.last).then((_) {
                    logger.d("TEXT SENT : ${sentences.last}");
                  }).catchError((e) {
                    logger.e(e);
                  });
                  break;
                } else {
                  sentenceTokens.add(words[i]);
                }
              }
              if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
                _confidence = val.confidence;
              }
            });
          },
          partialResults: true, // enable partial results
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
      print('Listened text: $_text');
    }
  }



}
```

The issue with this is that even though it is in isListening state, after a while the app stops capturing audio. Specially after a small pause or silence. is this normal in this plugin or is there something I can do for the app to continuously listen to the audio even after a silence?

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended function of the speech-to-text library.

Official Documentation states this:

> Continuous speech recognition
> There have been a number of questions about how to achieve continuous speech recognition using this plugin. Currently the plugin is designed for short intermittent use, like when expecting a response to a question, or issuing a single voice command.

However, You can use pauseFor.

> [pauseFor] sets the maximum duration of a pause in speech with no words detected, after that it automatically stops the listen for you.

Remember, there is inbuilt pauseFor limit in some devices. So, it may pause even before your set time limit is reached.

```
_speech.listen(
        pauseFor: const Duration(seconds: 10),
```

You may change Duration to your liking.